# Clear Autocomplete data when a new item is searched

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, autocomplete

I am trying to use Autocomplete in SharePoint custom list. I have modified the Newform.aspx. I have used the below code for the autocomplete functionality:

```
var autocomplete = $("input[title='Skill Required Field']").autocomplete({
  minLength: 3,
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({                            
      url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'MySkills\')/items?$select=Title&$filter=startswith(Title, '" + request.term + "')",
      cache: false,
      method: "GET",
      headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" 
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) {
          if (result.Title) {
            titles.push(result.Title)
          }                             
        });
        return response(titles);
      },
      error: function( data ) {
        alert('search error');
      }
    });
  },
  focus: function(event, ui) {          
    return false;
  }
});
```

The above code works fine, but the issue is - If i search for a term and select it and if I again search for another term, then in the search results collection, the first searched result is also showing up.
How to clear the search result after each record selection.
Thanks

Comment: Where is `titles` defined?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   
var titles = [];

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example of the issue?

Comment: The problem is solved. I removed the titles declaration and added before the $each statement